# GTFS major vs minor update

Tags: diff, updates, gtfs

We are downloading new [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference) (basically zip of CSV files) data from multiple sources each day to see if an update has been updated. Right now, we just check if the zip themselves are different, and update if they are different.

The thing is, on some sources, the GTFS is changing each and every day. That's a problem for us, since this trigger an update of offline data on a lot of devices.

Most of the time, the update is minor (changed stop name, different IDs but same content, etc). I want to differentiate the major update (schedule change, new route) from the minor. Diff tools themselves are useless since each GTFS can have the same content but with different IDs and/or order in the CSVs.

Has anybody had the same problem? Is there tool out there that can help?